# Slowest query with many inner join make it faster postgres

Tags: laravel, postgresql

how to make this query faster it takes 31 second

```
select tbl1.name , tbl3.area_m2 , tbl4.description from table1 tbl1

inner join table2 tbl2 on tbl1.code = tbl2.parent_code

inner join table3 tbl3 on tbl3.parent_table_code = tbl2.code

inner join table4 tbl4 on tbl4.code = tbl3.parent_table_code

order by tbl1.code
```

Comment: You may find PostgreSQL's Matterialized Views helpful.

Comment: Please provide information as instructed here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info